# Can I use transaction like capability in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, transactions, triggers

I have an insert trigger which takes a set of column values from rows in table A and inserts some of them in table B and remaining in table C. I need this operation to be a transaction wherein if there is some error whilst data is inserted in table B and not C, the entire insertion operation should be rolled back.

I studied the manual and it says at the last of [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) page that transaction is not allowed in triggers

Is there a way to achieve what I want in mysql.

Comment: You could do the operations in a stored procedure, which would be the same transaction.

Comment: I need to start this operation when a new record is inserted in table A, so thats why I was using triggers. Can this be done thru stored procedures?

Comment: You can run more than one statement in a stored procedure.

Comment: So i use my transaction code inside the stored procedure and implement a transaction. Then call this procedure from the trigger. Is this possible in mysql

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, but how you do it depends on your version.

First of all, triggers are themselves transactional; in your situation, you have an insert trigger that performs two further inserts. If one of those fails, you will get your desired effect.

Consider the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE a (colA INT);
CREATE TABLE b (colB INT);
CREATE TABLE c (colC INT);
delimiter :
CREATE TRIGGER testtrig BEFORE INSERT ON a
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO b(colB) VALUES(NEW.colA);
    INSERT INTO c(banana) VALUES (NEW.colA); -- note the faulty column name
END;:
delimiter ;
```

Now, when I run an insert that fails, this happens:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO a VALUES (5);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'banana' in 'field list'
mysql> SELECT * FROM a;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

This matches your desired result.

More generally, if you have logic you can use to validate your data before attempting the insert, you can fail the trigger in different ways:

- In MySQL 5.5, you can use the [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) mechanism to raise an error from your trigger, thus causing it to fail the whole insert.
- Prior to MySQL 5.5, you can generate a deliberate error to fail the trigger.

I'm guessing you're using 5.0 from the link in your question, so if you need to, you can perform a deliberate error, for example deliberately insert into an invalid column, to fail a trigger. However, the situation you describe in your question is already handled transactionally, as described at the start of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You get what you asked for by default -- any error in a trigger causes the statement to fail.  So if there is a transaction on the statement, you get a rollback of the data to just before that statement.  If there is no transaction, then you don't.

Which is probably why creating or ending a transaction is not allowed in a trigger.

So no need for a stored procedure.  In fact, the stored procedure you call from the trigger might cause an error if it tries to create a transaction.

But feel free to use a stored procedure to start a transaction before doing the action that causes the trigger.