# MySQL Trigger invalidate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to invalidate a Before inset trigger so that the line will not be inserted in the table

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trig1
 ON MyTable
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
.
.
.
.
.
END
```

Can i use an other way that displays the error message rather than

```
INSERT into Mytable values (NULL)
```

Comment: Insert int ????

Comment: into sorry, just to make a DML error

Comment: You mean `raise_error` ?

Comment: my trigger is used to check some conditions ( Integrity constraints ) if one of the is not satisfied, the row must not be inserted, i was doing that with INSERT into Mytable values (NULL)
I am now looking for a more convenient way to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use transaction like capability in MySQL trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255608/can-i-use-transaction-like-capability-in-mysql-trigger)